# Python PyGame Moving Rectangle

Tags: python, object, pygame

I am struggling with moving a drawn rectangle on the screen in pygame, I am trying to create a Snake game. I am very new to Python and object oriented programming in general so it is probably a stupid mistake.  Code below.

```
#X coordinate of snake
lead_x = 300


#sets window position on screen
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (320,240)


#imports pygame module
import sys, pygame

#initialises pygame module
pygame.init()

#changes background colour to green
background_colour = 155, 188, 15
blue =(0,0,255)
red = (100,40,20)
#sets screen size 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

#changes the background colour
screen.fill(background_colour)

#creates rectangle on the screen
pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, [lead_x,lead_x,10,10])



#updates display to show new background colour
pygame.display.update()

#Sets the window title to 'Python'
pygame.display.set_caption('Python')

#closes the window when user presses X
running = True



#if cross is clicked set running = False
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

            #Controls

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x -= 10

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x += 10


  #if running = False close pygame window          
if running == False:
    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, [lead_x, lead_y, 10, 10])` in your game loop. As of right now you're drawing the rect on the screen only once, and that's in the beginning of the program. You want to continuously draw the rect at different `lead_x` and `lead_y` positions in order for a rect to move on the screen.

You should also put a `screen.fill(background_colour)` (to clear the previous drawing) and `pygame.display.update()` (to update the changes) in your loop as well.

**EDIT:** I noticed something: you probably want to create a variable `lead_y` and use `pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, [lead_x, lead_y, 10, 10])` so you don't move diagonally every time.

Comment: Thanks for your help I will try these things out and have a look at the documentation.

Comment: Still having trouble moved draw rectangle to the while running loop and put in those two things but now all I get is a blank screen with no rectangle.

Comment: Did you put `screen.fill(background_colour)` after `pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, [lead_x, lead_y, 10, 10])`? Just flip their positions and it should work. You generally want `screen.fill(background_colour)` before you draw anything.

Comment: The order of events should be: 1) draw, 2) update, 3) fill

Comment: Yes, but due to the looping nature they are both essentially the same things, the one I posted just makes the most sense to me

Comment: @Ethan Ohh, I misunderstood what you meant by update. If you mean `pygame.display.update()` then yes, they are both essentially the same.